# Не работают isset на кнопки внутри вызываемой функции php

Tags: php, html, веб-программирование, form, redbeanphp

Извиняюсь, что задаю этот вопрос уже 2й раз, но мне очень нужна помощь с этим фрагментом кода.
Я должен вызывать функцию, задавая параметры для действия кнопок, где будет рекурсия но уже с другими параметрами. Но if(isset) просто вызывается сам без нажатия на кнопку. Пожалуйста, подскажите в чем проблема. Не кидайтесь палками, я новичек.
Если менять isset на !empty - то нажатие не работает вовсе

```
    <?php
require "php/include_db.php";  

//$submit_1 = $_POST['location_button_1'];
//$submit_2 = $_POST['location_button_2'];
//$submit_3 = $_POST['location_button_3'];
//$submit_4 = $_POST['location_button_4'];
$array_buttons = array($_POST['location_button_1'], $_POST['location_button_2'], $_POST['location_button_3'], $_POST['location_button_4']);
$src = null;

          $locationInfo = R::load('locationsdb', 1);
            $src = $locationInfo->location_image;
            echo $src;
            setButton($locationInfo->location_travel);

         function setButton($locationInfo_travel){
            $arr_travels = explode(' ', $locationInfo_travel);
      for($i=0; $i<count($arr_travels); $i++){ // Просто вывод возможностей хода
          echo ", ", $arr_travels[$i];
      }//--------------------
             echo '<pre>'.print_r($_POST, true).'</pre>';
     if(!empty ($_POST['location_button_1'])){
            $locationInfo = R::load('locationsdb', $arr_travels[0]);
            $src = $locationInfo->location_image;
            echo $src;
            setButton($locationInfo->location_travel);
}if(!empty ($_POST['location_button_2'])){
            $locationInfo = R::load('locationsdb', $arr_travels[1]);
            $src = $locationInfo->location_image;
            echo $src;
            setButton($locationInfo->location_travel);
}if(!empty ($_POST['location_button_3'])){
            $locationInfo = R::load('locationsdb', $arr_travels[2]);
            $src = $locationInfo->location_image;
            echo $src;
}if(!empty ($_POST['location_button_4'])){
            $locationInfo = R::load('locationsdb', $arr_travels[3]);
            $src = $locationInfo->location_image;
            echo $src;
}
}

?>
```

Форма:

```
<div class="location_buttons_container">
            <div class="buttons_container">
            <form method="post" action="Game.php">
                <ul class="buttons_menu">
                    <li>Локации</li>
                    <li ><span ><button id="location_button_1" name="location_button_1" value="selected">Главные ворота</button></span><em>3 сек.</em></li>
                    <li><span><button name="location_button_2" value="selected">Торговый квартал</button></span><em>2 сек</em></li>
                    <li><span><button name="location_button_3" value="selected">Замок</button></span><em>5 сек</em></li>
                    <li><span><button name="location_button_4" value="selected">Гильдия</button></span><em>4 сек</em></li>
                </ul>
                    </form>
                
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: `setButton` же вызывается безусловно. Что ты ожидаешь? Вызывай тогда `setButton` если тольк например `$_POST` не пуст.

Answer (score 1):

`isset` будет работать всегда, потому что приходит пустая строка, даже когда `value` нет, а вот в вашем случае нужно сделать следующее:

1. Заменить `isset` на `!empty`.
2. Добавить ко всем `<button name="location_button_*">` ещё значение `value="selected"` и тогда будет работать `!empty` как вам нужно.

Comment: Всеравно, я сделал, что вы сказали и все срабатывает само как было и функция срабатывает бесконечно,

Comment: Быть не может, что приходит в `$_POST` и что изменили в коде?

Comment: Заменил isset на !empty и задал кнопкам selected

Comment: В пост написано selected

Comment: Ну тогда всё должно работать, покажите новый код, который получился, видимо в нём что-то осталось от старого кода.

Comment: Я изменил вопрос, взгляните

Comment: Проверил локально, всё нормально выполняется, в $_POST приходит только одно значение, есть ещё вариант, сделать всем name `location_button`, а `value` уже от 1 до 4, и тогда проверять на `value`, он будет более правильный.

Comment: Всеравно, при нажатии на кнопку все зацикливает

Comment: Что значит зацикликвает? Я вижу часть php кода и не понимаю о чем речь.

Comment: При нажатии на кнопку вызывается этот же метод, но уже с другими параметрами и ждет следующего нажатия. По планам должно быть так. Но после нажатия на кнопку if !empty начинает выполнятся сам по себе и таким образом зацикливается